# invert needs a Pair?

Tags: raku

The [`invert`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/List.pm6#L755-L757) method for Lists should return the inverted sequence, or at least that's what the source seems to imply. However:

```
say (1,3,2).invert
```

fails with:

```
(exit code 1) Type check failed in invert; expected Pair but got Int (1)␤  in block <unit>
```

The documentation does not help, because it's LTA in this area (and missing for List). But the source code does not admit any ambiguous interpretation. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you intended to use the [reverse](https://docs.raku.org/routine/reverse) method.  Well, if you want the result to be `(2,3,1)`.

It looks like the documentation of `List.invert` is indeed missing.  It is intended to work only on a `List` that consists of `Pair`s.  I'll write that up now.

EDIT: doc added with https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/0ee3245776

Comment: So I got the list part right, but I didn't know the second part. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Perl6, operators subroutines and methods have a singular purpose for a given name.

In the case of the infix `+` operator it is to add two numbers. So if it is given something that is not a number it tries to turn it into a number before adding.

In the case of the [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) method, its fundamental purpose is to invert a Pair object. That is swap the `.key` and the `.value` of a Pair.

So everywhere that [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) can be used, it does so in the way that is most like inverting a Pair object.

---

On a Pair object with a singular `.value`, it swaps the key and the value.

```perl6
say ('a' => 'A').invert;
# (A => a)
```

If the `.value` is not singular it gives you a sequence where each value is now the key of its own Pair.

```perl6
say ('a' => ('A', 'B')).invert;
# (A => a B => a)
```

Note that [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) always returns a sequence to be consistent. Even on that first example.

On a Hash it does it on all of the key / value pairs.

```perl6
say %( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).invert.sort;
# (A => 1 A => a B => a B => b)
```

On a List, it could do it one of two ways.

1. It could use the index as the key, exactly like [`.antipairs`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/antipairs) does.

   ```perl6
   say ( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).antipairs.sort;
   # ((1 => A) => 2 (a => (A B)) => 0 (b => B) => 1)

   say ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ).antipairs;
   # (a => 0 b => 1 c => 2)
   ```
2. It could go through each of the Pairs in the list like it currently does.

   ```perl6
   say ( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).invert.sort
   (A => 1 A => a B => a B => b)
   ```

Since [`.antipairs`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/antipairs) already works like [`.pairs`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/pairs) except the opposite, there is really no reason for [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) to also work like it. That would have also made [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) less like a Pair method.

This also has the nice effect that you can get the Pairs from a Hash as a list then call [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) on it, and it will work like just calling [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) on the Hash directly.

```perl6
say %( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).invert.sort;
# (A => 1 A => a B => a B => b)

say %( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).list.invert.sort;
# (A => 1 A => a B => a B => b)
```

It also means that you can call [`.invert`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert) several times and it stays consistent.

```perl6
say %( 'a' => ('A','B'), 'b' => 'B', 1 => 'A' ).invert.invert.invert.sort;
# (A => 1 A => a B => a B => b)
```